# How to set splash screen in ionic4

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I’m migrating source code from ionic3 to ionic4.

I copied the ionic3 resouces folder to the ionic4 project.
However, the cordova symbol appears on the splash screen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5BlC.png)
I wonder why.
Please teach me how to change splash screen in ionic4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After copying, you need to run `ionic cordova resources` command that will recreate the resources (icons and splash) with the icon.png and splash.png file

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing new for splash screen change.
You can create splash screen and logo the same as earlier by

```
ionic cordova resources android/ios
```

for icon required : 1024 x 1024 png

for splash required:2732 x 2732 png

Comment: After I did that, the Cordova image changed to the ionic default image, but the image I created is not displayed.

Comment: Inside resources/   there must be two files splash.png and icon.png. Please check that and fire command again.

Comment: you can replace your image with above specified size.

Comment: I want to use my image for splash screen. But, resources folder's splash.png and icon.png is ionic default image. is it ok?

Comment: My image are on [resources/android] and [resources/ios].

Comment: Replace those two images which are already there.Put your images there and fire that command again

Comment: Thank you! The image of splash.png is displayed. But it is strange because the image of 2732x2732 is displayed.

Comment: There is a beautiful scaled image in the ios folder. Is this not used?

Comment: No you have to put those images in resources folder only with above specified size. and then that command will generate images again in android and ios folder

Comment: Is the image actually displayed in the resources folder? Or is it an ios folder?